# Error with code in the deactivated section of app.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8

In my app I want to properly kill the application when the user exits to start; for security reasons, however...

I get the following error:

`InvalidOperationException was unhandled Navigation is not allowed when the task is not in the foreground. Error: -2147220990`

When I put the code

```
new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit();
```

In the Deactivated event in App.xaml.cs so the application is truly killed when the user exits. – Newbie yesterday

Any way to solve this while keeping code in the deactivated event?
Or any way to achieve the same result?

additional info: It is a Windows Phone Portrait Page, so please tell me of any using statements I should add, if appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bad experience for the user. A WP user expects to go back to the last app when they press the home button then the back button. Why do you want to kill the app?

Comment: It is a passwords storage app, which is why this function is necessary

Comment: when the app is suspended, simply reset the state of your app so that if the user resumes the app, they will have to enter the password again.

Comment: What do you mean reset the state of the app